# Log4j is not writing logs to log file in ubuntu server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ubuntu, log4j

Here is my **log4j.properties** file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, INFO, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/ec2-user/usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/logs/MapMyStressBackend.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I am using Spring MVC. I have placed the log4j.properties file in ***resources*** folder. Please help me fix this. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

You can only specify one level:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
```

The file must be in `src/main/resources` if you are using a Maven structure project.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes i have placed it in `\src\main\resources` and I am using gradle. When I export my project to .war file and deploy it in server, will the **log4j.properties** still be there?